# C++ Random Generated Numbers

Tags: c++, random, multidimensional-array

I'm busy with a game and need to place a number into a 2D array at random places on the array. How can I do that?

I have

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
   {
      array[1 + rand() % row][1 + rand() % col] == 5;
   }
}
```

My program crashes when I run it. What could the problem be?

Comment: Show the declaration of `array`.

Comment: Arrays are 0-based, not 1-based.

Comment: Also, you are using `==` and not assignment `=` was this just a typo, or is this your real code?

Comment: and the assignment is iterated rows*cols times, so you will end up with a matrix with random number of 5s.

Comment: These loops don't make sense, you don't even use `i` and `j` (for each cell you pick another random cell)

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, arrays are zero-based so you have generate numbers in the range `[0,n-1]`.

Also, you're comparing instead of assigning (note the `==`)

Also, use more modern random generators, they're not only better in the sense of producing correct distributions, but also a lot more easy to use (no more arithmetic fiddling). For example, with [C++11's random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), you would have the following (this can also be achieved with [boost](http://www.boost.org/libs/random/) for pre-c++03):

```
std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> disRows(0, rows-1);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> disCOls(0, cols-1);
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
   {
      array[disRows(gen)][disCols(gen)] = 5;
   }
}
```

Also, the double loop doesn't make much sense here, if you want to randomly assign 5 'N' times, just loop from `0` to `N` (`N` could be `rows*cols`)

Answer (score 1):

`array[1 + rand() % row][1 + rand() % col]`

is incorrect because the first element is at position 0, not 1.

Try `array[rand() % row][ rand() % col]`

EDIT : 
`rand() % n` returns numbers from `0` to `n-1`. In your case adding 1 make it possible to try to access the element at position `row` or `col`, which are not valid indexes. And even if you wrote

`array[1 + rand() % (row-1)][1 + rand() % (col-1)]`

It is not truly random as both the first row and the first column will never be touched.

Comment: the question is how do you place the value 5 at random places in the array.

Comment: if `rand() % row` return `row-1` then `1 + rand() % row` is `row`, which is out of bound.

Comment: Yes i got that and it does not give me errors now it does not display the 5 in the array

Comment: @JonathanGeers: see my answer or read the third comment on your question, you use `==` instead of `=`